# ArcGIS Online Web Map JSON ID Property

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, web-mapping

I am programmatically creating web maps via the ArcGIS Online REST API and noticed that the webmap json spec has an ***id*** property but I'm not sure where it comes from or how to best set it.

For a given feature layer, how can I obtain the "id" shown below in order to dynamically create the webmap json?

```
{"operationalLayers":[
  {"id":"Collector_Template_Feature_Service_1452",
  "layerType":"ArcGISFeatureLayer",
  "url":"http://services1.arcgis.com/....",
  "visibility":true,
  "opacity":1,
  "itemId":"73830d6b39e948eaa48286629d2ff7d2" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on your usage, but, usually, I just make it up and just make sure it's unique. Programmatically, I might fetch the layer name, replace spaces with underscore, lowercase everything, and perhaps tack on a unique number from a counter...

Comment: So do you think this id property needs only to be unique within of the webmap?  I guess i could see the scenario where the same webmap has multiple versions of the same layer which could require an additional id.